# Ios how to post multiple Custom objects using Alamofire

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire

Hi i am new to iOS and I am using Alamofire for network calls. The things were going good and I am facing no trouble in making network calls. But since I have to post my custom object I am having no luck. so here are the things I was doing before

```
let parameters: Parameters = [
        "Phone": phone,
        "ApiKey":"x-y-z"
    ]
```

this was working fine.

but now I have to post my objects like

```
let parameters: Parameters = [
        "ApiKey": Common.API_KEY,
        "cardModel": cardModel,
        "clientModel" : clientModel
    ]
```

My cardModel and client model are already converted in Json string i am just putting them into dictionary. the converted model looks like these

```
"cardModel": {
    "ExpiryYear": 2018,
    "ExpiryMonth": 1,
    "CardNumber": "55555",
    "CardHolderName": "xyz"
}
```

so I am putting these serialized models in the dictionary and post this data into request body using Alamofire.

But on server side these Models are null. Any idea how to put custom model in the way I want ? please help

**PS** I just print out my parameters dictionary and I have examined this output

```
    ["ApiKey": "x-y-z",
     "\cardModel\": "{
     "\ExpiryYear\": 2018,
     "\ExpiryMonth\": 1,
     "\CardNumber\": "\55555\",
     "\CardHolderName\": "\xyz\"
    }
]
```

I put that parameters json printed output in jsonLint and it was wrong format. I just removed the "\" and replaced [] with {} and then it appears to be valid Json

So what I should do now???? please help

**Update1:**
this is valid json for my endpoint (sending from android)

```
{
"ApiKey": "XXX-XXX-XXX",
"cardModel": {
    "CardHolderName": "Fjj",
    "CardNumber": "555",
    "CardExpiryMonth": 1,
    "CardExpiryYear": 2018
    ......
}
```

}

Comment: It depends on your API, does your API needs JSON within JSON? If not, don't do this, and do simply `"clientModel" : clientModelDictionaryVersion`, not the JSONString one. If you can't do it back easily, just convert it to Data in utf8, and use JSONSerialization to convert that data into a Dictionary.

Comment: I have converted it, and my endpoint required data in the format posted in answer. Just updated now check the answer

Comment: That's not JSON within JSON. So, instead of using `clientModel`, send the Dictionary that help you construct the String.

Comment: I am not getting you

Comment: I just wanted to know how to put cardModel (which is string ) into parameters dictionary

Comment: Why do you have a String at first? Else, `let cardModelJSONData = String.init(data, encoding:.utf8); let dict = try? JSONSerialization(with: cardModelJSONData, options:[])` and use that `dict` .

Comment: let parameters: Parameters = [
        "ApiKey": Common.API_KEY,
        "cardModel": cardModel,
        "clientModel" : clientModel
    ] 

here clientModel and cardModel are purely generated using the way u assumed

Answer (score 0):

First you need to have a method/computed property that converts your model into a dictionary of type `[String: AnyObject]` or `[String: Any]`.
Then instead of adding your model into your parameter dictionary add the model dictionary like in below example.

```
class CardModel: NSObject {
    var expiryYear: Int?
    var expiryMonth: Int?
    var cardNumber: String?
    var cardHolderName: String?


    var jsonDict: [String: AnyObject] {
        var json: [String: AnyObject] = [:]//Initializing an Empty Dictionary
        json["expiryYear"] = expiryYear as AnyObject // Inserting expiryYear into Dictionary
        json["expiryMonth"] = expiryMonth as AnyObject // Inserting expiryMonth into Dictionary
        json["cardNumber"] = cardNumber as AnyObject // Inserting cardNumber into Dictionary
        json["cardHolderName"] = cardHolderName as AnyObject // Inserting cardHolderName into Dictionary
        return json // returning newly populated dictionary
    }
}

func requestToServer(cardModel: CardModel) {
    var parameters = [String: AnyObject]()
    parameters["ApiKey"] = "dfv12345df234t" as AnyObject
    parameters["cardModel"] = cardModel.jsonDict as AnyObject// adding card model dictionary into you paramters dictionary.

    //Same logic will be use for your next clientModel
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you read up on the [`Codable` protocol](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types), it is a very elegant way to map basic Swift-types to JSON-data. A Playground will help you with the following

```
import Cocoa

let jsonData = """
{
    "ApiKey": "XXX-XXX-XXX",
    "cardModel": {
        "CardHolderName": "Fjj",
        "CardNumber": "555",
        "CardExpiryMonth": 1,
        "CardExpiryYear": 2018
    }
}
""".data(using: .utf8)!
// ... missing here (but added a closing brace for cardModel

struct CardModel: Codable {
    let holderName: String
    let number: String
    let expiryMonth: Int
    let expiryYear: Int

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case holderName = "CardHolderName"
        case number = "CardNumber"
        case expiryMonth = "CardExpiryMonth"
        case expiryYear = "CardExpiryYear"
    }
}

struct ApiCardPayment: Codable {
    let apiKey: String
    let cardModel: CardModel

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case apiKey = "ApiKey"
        case cardModel
    }
}

do {
    let apiPayment = try JSONDecoder().decode(ApiCardPayment.self, from:jsonData)
    print(apiPayment)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

This is much easier to handle than the `[String:AnyObject]` casting nightmare you will probably have to interpret otherwise. Besides the error messages of the `JSONDecoder` have been improving rapidly and it is now rather good at pointing out what is going wrong.

P.S.: Of course there is also `JSONEncoder().encode()`, but that is just the easy part anyways.